# Sending Messages with NanoMessageBus

Tags: .net, msmq

I'm trying to configure NanoMessageBus just to "set and forget" send a message to MSMQ.  I can't seem to configure a send-only endpoint with NanoMessageBus. A UoW or TransactionScope is really un-necessary for me in this case.  Any thoughts?

Comment: So, I've realized that I just need to allow Autofac to inject the UnitOfWork and call UnitOfWork.Complete() once I've called Bus.Send  Ordinarily, the unitOfWork would execute the transaction by registering it like: 
builder.RegisterType<TransactionScopeUnitOfWork>()                .As<IHandleUnitOfWork>).InstancePerHttpRequest().InstancePerLifetimeScope();  Not sure why the callback isn't firing, but the call to complete works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

So after a few days of looking I figured out my stupidity. To wire up the Unit of work you can do this:

```
builder.RegisterType<TransactionScopeUnitOfWork>()
    .As<IHandleUnitOfWork>).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But, you have to specify the callback delegate (duh):

```
.OnRelease(u => u.Complete())
```

Hope this helps someone else.  Even though NanoMessageBus isn't widely used, I've used NServiceBus extensively on another large project - and I think there's a simplicity with nano message bus when NServiceBus is overkill.